# setting radio button checked when form loading (vb net)?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to select one of my RadioButton from a different Group Boxes (only one radio button needs to be check from all radio buttons) programmatically (when the form is loaded).

I'm loading datagridview  value to a  variable.
Now, I want to select the radio button corresponding to the value in the variable. .

I tried simple code using else if and select case. But both are not working?

```
{ Dim SpecimenName As String = frmMain.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        If SpecimenName = "" Then
            'RadioButton1.AutoCheck()
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "Michanical" Then
            RadioButton1.PerformClick()
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "Manage" Then
            RadioButton2.PerformClick()
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "Civil" Then
            RadioButton3.Checked = True
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "Electronics" Then
            RadioButton4.Checked = True
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "Supply" Then
            RadioButton5.Checked = True
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "Landscaping" Then
            RadioButton6.Checked = True
        ElseIf SpecimenName Like "P&D" Or SpecimenName Like "Project" Then
            RadioButton7.Checked = True
        End If}
```

Comment: Is your grid bound to a data source? When do you load the data into the grid? In which event handler do you execute your posted code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `RadioButton1.Checked = True` in the `Form_Shown` event.

`Form_Load` will not work if that is where you are setting the checked values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am very new this and please specify more please.